# Tinting ImageView not working on Android 5.0. Ideas how to make it work again?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-5.0-lollipop

In an application I've built I noticed that the ImageViews are not tinted on devices running the new Android Lollipop. This is the code that used to work correctly on older versions of the OS:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descr_background_image"
            android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_white_color"
            android:tint="@color/intent_circle_green_grey" />
```

and this is the drawable that is loaded in the ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/white" android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Once again, this is working correctly on devices running JellyBean/Kitkat, but the tint has no effect on devices running Lollipop. Any ideas how to fix it? Is it a bug in the OS, or should I start tinting the image differently?

Comment: OS bug that's been fixed for a future release. ImageView's tint attribute was updated to use Drawable.setTint() rather than Drawable.setColorFilter(), but GradientDrawable didn't support setTint(). There is not really a good workaround for this from XML, but you can call setColorFilter() from code.

Comment: Awesome, it's good to know that you've already taken care of it! Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per @alanv comment, here goes the hacky fix to this bug. Basic idea is to extend `ImageView` and apply `ColorFilter` right after inflation:

```
public class TintImageView extends ImageView {

    public TintImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ColorStateList imageTintList = getImageTintList();
            if (imageTintList == null) {
                return;
            }

            setColorFilter(imageTintList.getDefaultColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    }
}
```

As you might guess, this example is somewhat limited (`Drawable` set after inflation tint won't be updated, only default color of `ColorStateList` is used, and maybe something else), but if you got the idea you can fit it to your use-case.

Answer (score 20):

Use the `AppCompatImageView` like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_appcompat_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        android:tint="#636363"
    />
```

Make sure you have the latest `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` in your app's `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

this code work for me in android lollipop

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView,ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor(chartTable.getReport().getButtonColor())));
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes in xml drawable coded color and alpha number. you need change or remove this. like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:alpha="0.8">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M16,1L8,1C6.34,1 5,2.34 5,4v16c0,1.66 1.34,3 3,3h8c1.66,0 3,-1.34 3,-3L19,4c0,-1.66 -1.34,-3 -3,-3zM14,21h-4v-1h4v1zM17.25,18L6.75,18L6.75,4h10.5v14z"/>
</vector>
```

to:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="@android:color/white">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M16,1L8,1C6.34,1 5,2.34 5,4v16c0,1.66 1.34,3 3,3h8c1.66,0 3,-1.34 3,-3L19,4c0,-1.66 -1.34,-3 -3,-3zM14,21h-4v-1h4v1zM17.25,18L6.75,18L6.75,4h10.5v14z"/>
</vector>
```

just read the xml image and remove **alpha** or change color of tine. if you need.