# How can I get an ImageView's tint color programatically?

Tags: android, imageview

I can set an `ImageView`'s tint color by using `setColorFilter(int color)` but `getColorFilter()` returns a `ColorFilter` object and not an `int` color. It seems like I can cast `ColorFilter` into a `PorterDuffColorFilter` which has a public `getColor()` method but still needs to be called with reflection since it is annotated with `@hide`. That seems hacky and isn't guaranteed to not break.

Am I missing something or has someone come up with a better solution that isn't as hacky?

Answer (score -1):

You may consider using ColorStateList getImageTintList ()

Please see the link [Tinting ImageView not working on Android 5.0. Ideas how to make it work again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174893/tinting-imageview-not-working-on-android-5-0-ideas-how-to-make-it-work-again)

Comment: That method seems to only return the initial tint color and is not updated for subsequent changes to the tint color (as stated by the original answerer in your link).

Comment: Did you find any solution? @RitzMalheur